# TPageControl content does not update in DLL

Tags: dll, c++builder-2009

In C++ Builder 2009, I have DLLs that export `TFrame` subclasses to my EXE main program. There is a `TPageControl` object in the `TFrame` subclass. When the `TFrame` is loaded into the EXE and displayed on a `TForm`, no matter if I change the tab of the `TPageControl`, the content of the `TPageControl` remains the same, but the active tab is updated.

I never met this kind of problem when I use `TPageControl` directly in the EXE main program. Does it have anything to do with DLL and VCL limitations?

Comment: In order to share VCL objects across the DLL boundary, you should create a BPL package instead of a DLL.  A BPL is a DLL that has built-in support for the RTL/VCL.

Comment: Hi Remy. Thanks for your kindly reply and grammar correction. I understand that developing plugins in a BPL package instead of a DLL might solve the problem, I wonder, however, is there any other solution? For example, the author in http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=84875 posted the same problem and claimed that he had solved it by realizing that it had something to do with `TPageControl` parent window handle.

Comment: If you read the comments in that QC ticket, the issue was related to differences in RTTI when accessing objects across the DLL boundary.  Specifically, when `TPageControl` calls `GetParentForm()` and it was returning nil instead of the EXE's `TForm`. A BPL would solve that problem. Otherwise, you would have to recompile the DLL with a modified `Forms` unit to work around the RTTI problem in `GetParentForm()`. Switching to a BPL would also solve versioning conflicts between different RTLs if you update the EXE to a different IDE version and forget to update the DLL to match.

Comment: Hi Remy. If I put a complete `TForm` containing `TPageControl` in a DLL, can I get rid of this issue that `TPageControl` can not find its parent form?

Comment: Yes, because the RTTI of the `TForm` would match what the code inside the DLL is expecting. But moving the `TForm` itself into the DLL presents its own share of issues, depending on how you are using it.

Comment: Hi Remy. I have solved my problem by putting `TForm` in a DLL directly. Thanks a lot for your reply. I have another question in my project not related to this problem directly. I create a `TForm` subclass by Form Designer and put some components and event handlers on it. Is it a common practice to inherit from such `TForm` subclass to add more components and event handlers on it? Or is it advised to create new `TForm` subclass with original and new components?